# No material widget found in test

Tags: flutter, testing

I am getting the `No material widget found` error when I run the following test, even though I am wrapping it in a MaterialApp. Any pointers to why that is?

```
void main() {
  final mockExam = examMocks[0];
  Widget createGridItem() => Provider<ExamInformation>.value(
        value: ExamInformation(
            examSpecifications: mockExam.examSpecifications,
            examImage: mockExam.examImage,
            questionList: mockExam.questionList),
        child: ExamGridItem(),
      );

  testWidgets('Exam grid item displays Footer', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(home: createGridItem()));

    final gridItemFooterFinder = find.byType(Footer);
    expect(gridItemFooterFinder, findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

Detailed error log:

```
The following assertion was thrown building _InkResponseStateWidget(gestures: [tap], mouseCursor:
null, BoxShape.circle, dirty, state: _InkResponseState#3ef96):
No Material widget found.
_InkResponseStateWidget widgets require a Material widget ancestor.
In material design, most widgets are conceptually "printed" on a sheet of material. In Flutter's
material library, that material is represented by the Material widget. It is the Material widget
that renders ink splashes, for instance. Because of this, many material library widgets require that
there be a Material widget in the tree above them.
To introduce a Material widget, you can either directly include one, or use a widget that contains
Material itself, such as a Card, Dialog, Drawer, or Scaffold.

The specific widget that could not find a Material ancestor was:
  _InkResponseStateWidget
The ancestors of this widget were:
  ...
  InkResponse
  Positioned
  Stack
  GridTile
  Consumer<ExamInformation>
  ...
```

Comment: try to avoid putting screenshots of code and create code blocks instead when posting on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your widget inside Material widget.

Example:

```dart
Material(child: InkWell())
```

The widget causing this error was shown in error description:

```
  InkResponse
  Positioned
  Stack
  GridTile
  Consumer<ExamInformation>
```

Comment: That is the widget tree with Consumer<ExamInformation> at the root. Consumer<ExamInformation> is returned by the build method of ExamGridItem. This, in turn, is returned by the createGridItem method which is wrapped in the MaterialApp in the test.

Comment: Based on your response, I wrapped my widget in a scaffold in the test and then wrapped that again in MaterialApp. Do you have any idea why MaterialApp on its own didn't work?

Comment: @mirage because some widgets require `Material` widget. That's not same as `MaterialApp` . MaterialApp implements navigation theming and other global configs. But Material is used for drawing content on it (for example InkWell draws content on material)

Comment: "That is the widget tree with Consumer<ExamInformation> " I think the issue is related to "Stack > Positioned > InkResponse" widget.